# Send and receive mail from same class?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Just testing it out at the moment, but can you send and receive mail from the same class as below?

```
package com.mailserver;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger; 
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Part;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MailHandlerServlet extends HttpServlet {
public static final Logger _log = Logger.getLogger(MailHandlerServlet.class.getName());

@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
throws ServletException, IOException {

    sendmail(); 

try {

Properties props = new Properties();
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session, req.getInputStream());

//Extract out the important fields from the Mime Message
String subject = message.getSubject();

_log.info("Got an email. Subject = " + subject);

String contentType = message.getContentType();
_log.info("Email Content Type : " + contentType);



printParts(message);

//Parse out the Multiparts
//Perform business logic based on the email
}
catch (Exception ex) {
_log.log(Level.WARNING, "Failure in receiving email : " + ex.getMessage());
}
}

private static void printParts(Part p) throws IOException, MessagingException {
Object o = p.getContent();

if (o instanceof String) {
System.out.println("This is a String");
System.out.println((String)o);
}
else if (o instanceof Multipart) {
System.out.println("This is a Multipart");
Multipart mp = (Multipart)o;

int count = mp.getCount();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
printParts(mp.getBodyPart(i));
}
}
else if (o instanceof InputStream) {
System.out.println("This is just an input stream");
InputStream is = (InputStream)o;
int c;
while ((c = is.read()) != -1)
System.out.write(c);
}
}

private static void sendmail() {

    _log.info("Email Sent");

    Properties props2 = new Properties();
    Session session2 = Session.getDefaultInstance(props2, null);

    String msgBody = "...";

    try {
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session2);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("booya@cyclonecentral.appspotmail.com", "Example.com Admin"));
        msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                         new InternetAddress("me@gmail.com", "Mr. User"));
        msg.setSubject("Your Example.com account has been activated");
        msg.setText(msgBody);
        Transport.send(msg);

    } catch (AddressException e) {
        // ...
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        // ...
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Needless to say, its not sending me mail which has me wondering if its because theres some conflict?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's absolutely no reason you shouldn't be able to send email from anywhere in your app, including in a mail handler. If it's not working, you should check your request logs to determine why.

Your code would be a *lot* easier to read if it were indented correctly.